# A Python function that returns the number of k permutations of n items

Tags: python, permutation

At first, I was asked to implement the number P(n) of of (n-) permutations of n items satisfies the following recurrence:
[image]

I did so successfully (num_permutation_v1):
[image]

Now, I am asked to extend the function num_permutation_v1, to num_permutation_v2, to allow for an optional argument "k":
[image]

Here is the function that I wrote and tried to run, but it failed the test cases:

def num_permutation_v2(n, k=None):
"""Compute the number of k-permutations of n items.

```
Parameters
----------
n: int
    Number of items to permute.
k: int
    Optional argument indicating the size of each permutation.
    Default: n

Returns
-------
int:
    Number of k-permutations of n items.
"""
if k is not None and 0<=k<=n:
    ban = 1
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        ban *= i
    for i in range(1, n-k+1):
        ban //= i
    return ban
elif k is not None and k == 0:
    return 1
else:
    ban = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        ban *= 1
    return ban
```

For the function num_permutation_v2, I have tried to make it return num_permutation_v2(n)/num_permutation_v2(n-k), when 0 <= k <= n, else: return 0. I was expecting that assert num_permutation_v2(3) == 6 but I am getting 1 instead.

Comment: Why not call your first function from the second? Also -- unless your code *needs* to use the recurrence, you could use the fact that `Pn,k = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*(n-k+1)`, which is a product that can be easily computed with a for-loop (or by using `math.prod` if you are allowed to use imports).

Comment: You're asked to extend v1, so keep its code, add a 2nd optional argument *k; if k is empty, execute the code from v1; if not, execute the 2nd algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the revised function could be (you could tweak it to send an error if there are more than 2 arguments, but I decided to simply ignore arguments after the 2nd one); note that I didn't do exactly what I said in my comment, in order to reduce the code:

```
def num_permutations_v2(n,*k):
    if n < 0 or (k and k[0] < 0) or (k and k[0] > n):
        return 0
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if k:
        return num_permutations_v2(n)/num_permutations_v2(n-k[0])
    return n*num_permutations_v2(n-1)
```

Another version that is more in line with what I said:

```
def num_permutations_v2(n,*k):
    if not k:
        if n > 0:
            return n*num_permutations_v2(n-1)
        elif n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        if n < 0 or k[0] < 0 or  k[0] > n:
            return 0
        elif n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return num_permutations_v2(n)/num_permutations_v2(n-k[0])
```